# How to clean up RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

I don't know if there are jobs waiting to be executed in the RabbitMQ queue, how could I check it and clean up?

Opening the `var/` folder I see many export files, not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are jobs waiting to be executed you will see them in the **queue_lock** table in your database.

To clean up the queue in the database and run any process again before starting forcing it, you can truncate your queue lock table and mview in your database, remove generated CSV files that are not completed, run the actions that were stuck and run a manual consumer without memory limit, as these commands below are doing.

### Database

```
TRUNCATE 'queue_lock';

TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_data_exporter_products_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_attribute_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_category_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_price_cl';
TRUNCATE 'cataloginventory_stock_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogsearch_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'customer_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'design_config_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_categories_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_thesaurus_cl';
TRUNCATE 'inventory_cl';
TRUNCATE 'salesrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_product_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_rule_product_cl';

UPDATE `mview_state` SET `version_id` = '0';
```

### Terminal

```
rm -rf ./var/importexport_*;
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumers:list;
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all &
```